# Spring-boot JpaRepository when using custom functions

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using JpaRepository, the problem Appears when using inside function in the repo class like this and if i use Jpa functions without custom functions it works fine

```java
@Repository
public interface SystemEventRepository extends JpaRepository<SystemEvent, Integer> {
    SystemEvent findByEvent(String event);
}
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemEventRepository' defined in repository.SystemEventRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on AppConfig: class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.<init>(java.util.function.Supplier)' (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery and org.springframework.data.util.Lazy are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Comment: FYI: you don't need to put the `@Repository` annotation to the class, Spring knows what to do anyway when extending a `JpaRepository`.